# Kafka Consumer return doesn't match the Producers input

Tags: json, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have built a Java Kafka producer and consumer with SpringBoot

My producer sends a JsonObject like this:

```
@Service
public class Producer {
    
    @Autowired
    KafkaTemplate<String, JSONObject> kafkaTemplate;

    public void sendMessageToTopic(JSONObject message) {
        kafkaTemplate.send("seismic", message);
    }

}
```

My Consumer looks like this:

```
@Component
public class KafkaListeners {

    @KafkaListener(
        topics="seismic",
        groupId = "groupId"
    )
    void listener(JSONObject data) {
        System.out.println(data.toString());
    }

}
```

The consumer config like this:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServer;

    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfig() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);

        return properties;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, JSONObject> consumerFactory() {

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfig());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, JSONObject>> factory (ConsumerFactory<String, JSONObject> consumerFactory) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, JSONObject> factory = 
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, JSONObject>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);

        return factory;

    }
}
```

The producer properties:

```
public Map<String, Object> producerConfig() {
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

    return properties;
}
```

Now a sample output from the producer is (which has the type JSONObject):

```
ProducerId set to 1000 with epoch 0
{"date":"2023-07-05","depth":8,"latitude":38.1448,"longtitude":38.0947,"magnitude":3.1,"time":"18:01:18"}
```

The output from the consumer is:

```
{"mapType":"java.util.HashMap","empty":false}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can try it locally to see what's going wrong.

Comment: It looks like you use `JsonSerializer/JsonDeserializer`  from wrong packages. If that would be from Spring for Apache Kafka, then you'd fail with untrusted package: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#json-serde

Comment: The serializer / deserializer are from: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.

Comment: Is it maybe because I am using org.json to serialize ?

Comment: Possibly. Spring and Kafka use Jackson, by default. Import JsonNode, not JSONObject. Otherwise, use a POJO model

Comment: I have resolved it by creating custom Serealizers and Deserealizers, but thank you all for your help